# iOS Development: Which technology shall we use to mirror display of Photoshop to iOS device?

Tags: ios

Adobe Photoshop has a feature called "Remote Connection" which allow device to mirror preview of current design to the screen.

I want to build the app like that, but I don't know which technology that help to start research to archive this goal.

Hope anyone could give me an idea to getting start.

Thanks!

Edit (For anyone have the same question):
I found the answer: Should use Bongjour service and Adobe Also have the SDK and sample code. The Photoshop Touch SDK can be found here http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/sdk.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote connection is for apps to send and receive javascript packets through Photoshop's API. Check out their API guide. By the way its terribly buggy, outdated, and undocumented.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check their API

Comment: @RathaHin No problem, just beware that its very old and I had to rewrite a lot of code to get it working. (Also please mark answer correct if it is :p)